# Twitter share button not showing link

Tags: php, html, twitter, share

I am trying t add a twitter share button on my website. I have tried like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="es" data-size="large" 
data-count="none" 
data-url="http://localhost/pruebasmarty/Controlador/ServicioDetalle.php">
Twittear</a>

<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But the URL is not showing when the twitter widow is open, its just empty. Ive tried with

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="es" data-size="large" 
data-count="none" >Twittear</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

But its the same. Can anybody help me?

[image]

It doesn't show the link i want to share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try using an external URLS other than local host?

It seems like the localhost or any internal hostnames without proper tld is not recognized as a valid URL to be shared.

I checked the same tag with http://www.google.com and it works.

Comment: Mmm you are right. Thank you! i suppose that when the website is in a server it will work? @PremSriram